# Tinymce editor: edit url name - urlconverter:callback?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, href

I am using the tinymce editor has my textfield editor and want to edit the url when user enter urls. By edit I mean remove all the get parameters (I have accomplished that already).

However, the link which is displayed to the user is the normal url which is the orginial and not the edited one. But when you click on the url the url opens without the get paramets. That means, the urlconverter_callback is only editing the `href` attribute. My question now is how to change the url name as well? I haven't found and solution yet...

This is what I have got so far (somehow I am not able to get a version in a snippet to run..):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeParameters(url, node, on_save, name) {
        // Do some custom URL conversion
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));

        // Return new URL
        return url;
    }

    var editor_config = {
        menubar:false,
        statusbar: false,
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: [
            'paste link autolink',
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic strikethrough underline | link',
        paste_as_text: true,
        font_formats: 'Arial=arial',
        entity_encoding : 'raw',
        default_link_target: '_blank',
        link_assume_external_targets: 'https',
        urlconverter_callback : 'removeParameters',
        target_list: false,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                tinymce.triggerSave();
            });
        },
    };

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        tinymce.init(editor_config);
    });
</script>
```